# Numpy doesn't respond accurate in m1 macbook

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1

I have macbook pro m1 pro and I have tested some simple numpy commands on it and it doesn't respond correctly but if I check the same command in an online compiler it respond ok.
Can you help me please?

```
import numpy as np
y=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(np.linalg.det(y))
```

the result in my Macbook is : -9.51619735392994e-16
while the correct answer and also the online compiler answer is : 0.0

Comment: 64-bit float is only accurate to about 15 or 16 decimal places. The answer you're getting is within that accuracy.

Comment: so how should I make it right ?? It's troubling me in my calculations

Comment: Use `np.isclose()` to check equality rather than `==` when dealing with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two floats (or doubles etc) can be problematic. Generally, instead of comparing for exact equality they should be checked against an error bound. If they are within the error bound, they are considered equal.

Just round the results and you will always get 0. it is nothing to do with mac. it could be two instance on the same machine as well.

Comment: but I use the same command on another pc (which is not m1) and it returns 0.0. if I round the answer I will also get problems in getting answer for equations!!

Comment: it is the nature of floating point numbers. just round it.